# Proving Rate of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, nested-radicals

I am investigating the following coupled sequence:
\begin{align*}
y_0 &= 1\\
x_{n+1} &= \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{y_n}}\\
y_{n+1} &= \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x_{n+1}}}\\ 
\end{align*}
I am trying to show
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left |x_{n+1} - \varphi\right |}{\left |x_n - \varphi\right |} &= \frac{1}{4}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left |y_{n+1} - \varphi^{-1}\right |}{\left |y_n - \varphi^{-1}\right |} &= \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
where $\varphi = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

So far, I've shown:
\begin{align*}
        x_{n+1}^2 - \varphi^2 &= 1 + \frac{1}{y_n} - \varphi^2\\
        &= \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x_n - 1}} - \varphi\\
        &= \frac{1 + \frac{1}{x_n - 1} - \varphi^2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x_n - 1}} + \varphi}\\
        &= \frac{\frac{1}{x_n - 1} - \frac{1}{\varphi - 1}}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x_n - 1}} + \varphi}\\
        &= \frac{\varphi - x_n}{\left (\varphi - 1\right )\left (\sqrt{x_n^2 - x_n} + \varphi\left(x_n - 1\right ) \right )}\\
        \frac{x_{n+1} - \varphi}{\varphi - x_n} &= \frac{\varphi}{\left (x_{n+1} + \varphi\right )\left (\sqrt{x_n^2 - x_n} + \varphi\left(x_n - 1\right )\right )}\\
    \end{align*}
This result (which is true when the limits are substituted in) could be promising but I've come up on to a dead-end it seems.

Any help would be great.

Comment: so you haven't proved the individual limits yet? I think it's begging for one to consider $x_{n} + y_n$ and $x_ny_n$ and see that they converge to the coefficients of the quadratic $(t-\phi)(t-\phi^{-1}).$

Comment: @dezdichado I'm not sure how the square roots are dealt with there (are you doing a conjugation trick with $x_n + y_n$?). I do know the individual limits, and assuming convergence, it's not too difficult to determine.

Comment: that was just one idea. Also, your $x0$ is missing and there is an indexing issue with your work. Your recurrence for $x$ sequence in the end should only involve $x_{n+2}$ and  $x_n$. Besides, if $x_n\to\phi$, then eventually this term $\sqrt{x_n^2-x_n}$ becomes a complex number.

Comment: I mean $x_0 = \infty$ by back-substituting, but that doesn't matter as we only need one term from either $x$ or $y$ to determine all subsequent terms (there is no indexing issue, I could've written this as one sequence, but using this notation allows for easy working. For example, this sequence is equivalent to $z_{n} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{z_{n-1}}}$ with $z_0 = 1$). Also, $\phi^2 - \phi = 1$, not $-1$. Hence, $x_n \to \phi$ is reasonable (and correct).

Comment: I agree with dezdichado, can you please edit your question to give a value to $x_0$ in your definition? Otherwise the $x_n$'s are only defined for odd $n$'s and the $y_n$'s only for even $n$'s (your $z_n$ is $z_{2k}=y_{2k}$ and $z_{2k+1}=x_{2k+1}$).

Comment: @SharkyKesa you are right about the square root term but I don't understand your comment about $x_0=\infty .$ If this is true, then I am assuming this must be derived backward from $y_1 = 1$, which is backwardly derived from $x_2 = 2$ and so on. When does this stop? 

Even if you are correct about this and I am not seeing this, why introduce this unnecessary sloppiness into a problem that could simply be fixed by prescribing the initial value?

Comment: @dezdichado Argh! I see what you mean, sorry about that. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

After the edit, it should be simple. You have:
$$x_{n+1} = f(x_n): \quad f(x) = \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac 1x}}},\,\, x_1 =\sqrt{2}.$$

Some, but not too terrible, calculus will show that $1 <x<f(x)$ if $x\in (1,\varphi).$ This tells us that $x_n$ is increasing. In fact, after removing square roots $f(x)>x$ is equivalent to:
$$(x-1)^3(x+1)^2-x = (x^2-x-1)(x^3-x+1) < 0$$
which is easy to verify on $(1,\varphi).$

It's also trivially bounded too since because $f$ is a decreasing function:
$$f(x_n)\leq f(x_1) = \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}}.$$

So you have your convergence and the only thing left to do is to solve the equation:
$$x = f(x)\iff (x^2-x-1)(x^3-x+1) = 0.$$
The unique positive solution is $\varphi$ and the problem follows.

**EDIT:**

The part of the above work that says $x_n$ is increasing is incorrect, as I mistakenly computed $f(x_1) < \varphi.$ But in reality, $f(x_1)\approx 1.68...$ and indeed the sequence oscillates. However, this makes it possible for a simpler proof using OP's work. One simply needs to have a lower bound on $x_n$ and in fact $x_n > 1$ will work since:

$$\frac{x_{n+1} - \varphi}{\varphi - x_n} = \frac{\varphi}{\left (x_{n+1} + \varphi\right )\left (\sqrt{x_n^2 - x_n} + \varphi\left(x_n - 1\right )\right )} < \dfrac{\varphi}{1+\varphi} = \varphi^{-1}<1.$$
This proves $x_n\to\varphi$ and in return OP's equation above proves the convergence rate is $\dfrac 14.$

Comment: This does not directly answer the OP's question. And based on the way the question has been written, it is straightforward to deduce that they want to use the result of the limiting ratio to deduce that the sequence approaches the golden ratio, rather than use the knowledge of the sequence approaching the golden ratio to deduce the limiting ratio.

Comment: @JackTigerLam OP literally wrote he wanted to prove the rate of convergence. Rate of convergence is typically the next level of information after proving something converges as in establishing the rate of convergence is a stronger result than just proving convergence.

Comment: @dezdichado Are you sure $x_n$ is increasing? My given work would imply the $x_n$ is oscillatory around the limit, if $x_n \to \varphi$. Furthermore, using Python to generate the first $10$ values yields $[1.4142135623730951, 1.687530463435423, 1.602085620418655, 1.622104957295748, 1.61702156547447, 1.6182874257819875, 1.6179706502116171, 1.6180498246791526, 1.6180300298485029, 1.6180349784803003, 1.6180337413176096]$, further confirming the oscillatory nature.

Comment: @SharkyKesa you are right - I made the mistake manually computing $f(x_1).$ But that makes the proof even simpler - see the edit. It looks like you had done basically $95\%$ of the work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I wonder if there's a way of showing this without proving the limit. I've done something like that before for some other sequences, but they seem a bit simpler than this.